# My virtual path isn't working in release mode in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, release, virtual-path

My project (named Viper) seems to be working fine in debug mode on my dev PC.

The following line

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Setup")">Setup</a>
```

gives me the following link in the browser in dev, which works fine:

```
http://localhost/Viper/Setup
```

However, when I release this to the staging pc, when I look at the same link, I get this:

```
http://setup
```

Any idea why the release mode isn't capturing the virtual path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not use

```
@Html.ActionLink("Setup", "Index", "Setup")
```

if you need the relativa path you can use

```
@Url.Content("~/")
```

so in your case

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/" + Url.Action("Index","Setup"))" >Setup</a>
```

Comment: Same problem.  It happens on all of my @Url.Action's as well, so nothing is navigating correctly.

Comment: I tried changing it to <a href="@Url.Action("~/" + "Index", "Setup")">Setup</a>, but that just gives me the link http://setup/~/Index.

Comment: ok, but did you try `<a href="@Url.Content("~/" + Url.Action("Index","Setup"))" >Setup</a>` ?

Comment: Ah, sorry about the mis-read.  That seemed to work, however, I'm not really fond of having to put "~/" in front of all my controller calls.  I'm wondering if I don't have MVC 4 installed on my staging server?  I'm installing that now, so we'll see if that fixes anything.

Comment: great, good luck. Hope it works after installing MVC 4 on your server.